# Scrape list items into comma separated values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and trying to scrape an unordered list. I want the list items to be scraped into a list items separated with a comma. This is the list I want to scrape.

```
<div class="spec-list attributes-modality">
<h5 class="spec-subcat">Modality</h5>
<div class="col-split-xs-1 col-split-md-1">
<ul class="attribute-list copy-small">
<li class="">Individuals</li>
<li class="">Family</li>
<li class="">Group</li>
</ul></div></div>
```

This is my try:

```
modalitydiv = soup.find('div', class_='spec-list attributes-modality')
modality = modalitydiv.find('ul', class_='attribute-list copy-small').text.strip()
```

My try does give me only a list of list items line by line.

Individuals

Family

Group

Why do these does not appear in the same line and how can I scrape this list items into a comma separated list? can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the following output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc="""

<div class="spec-list attributes-modality">
<h5 class="spec-subcat">Modality</h5>
<div class="col-split-xs-1 col-split-md-1">
<ul class="attribute-list copy-small">
<li class="">Individuals</li>
<li class="">Family</li>
<li class="">Group</li>
</ul></div></div>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

p=', '.join([x.get_text(strip = True) for x in soup.select('ul.attribute-list.copy-small>li')])

print(p)
```

Output:

```
Individuals, Family, Group
```

Comment: It worked in separating the items with a comma. But still I get those in separate three lines in the csv. Not in the same line(In the same ).  They have larger spaces in between them. ```Trauma and PTSD
                                            , 
                                                    Addiction
                                            , 
                                                    Dual Diagnosis```  Like this. Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: @Devindi Siwurathna updated. Try again

Comment: It worked. Thankyou. Can you please explain me why you used 'attribute-list.copy-small' as the ul class, instead of 'attribute-list copy-small'? the original ul class have a space and you have used a dot. Can you please explain why is that? Or can you please suggest me any resource?

Comment: Because ul contains more than one class value. In css selector, classes are seperated by space that's why to select multiple classes we need dot to select each class instead of space. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens

You are using `strip()` that is only removing leading and trailing characters.

#### Solution

Use `split()` instead `strip()` to split string into a list:

```
modalitydiv = soup.find('div', class_='spec-list attributes-modality')
modality = modalitydiv.find('ul', class_='attribute-list copy-small').text.split()
```

#### Output

```
['Individuals', 'Family', 'Group']
```

Comment: It worked for this ul. But when I tried it for ul s which are having more than one word in the list item, ex: 'team and me', it separated it also into three objects. like, 'team', 'and','me'.